# Filter CloudWatch Logs to extract Instance ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an AWS Lambda function that is invoked when an instance gets terminated and this the message is stored in Amazon CloudWatch Logs.

I want to extract and filter these log messages to get a particular ID. How can I extract the logs and filter it using Python?

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, follow the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110490/cloud-computing-aws-azure-google-openstack-etc?referrer=Gtut7wQSWPk88jFJz_zqMg2) and up-vote some sample questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest method might be to **create a rule in Amazon CloudWatch Events** that triggers an AWS Lambda function. The function automatically passes information relating to the instance that was terminated. You can write the Lambda function in Python.

[image: Amazon CloudWatch Events]

This way, your function is automatically triggered whenever an instance is terminated, rather than having to look through logs.

Comment: Actually my main intend is to delete these terminated instances id automatically from my active directory

Comment: I am thinking of writing a code in python which will extract the messages from the queue and incorporate it as a lambda function and extract the specific instance id from that